# How is the Etherscan TokenTracker able to show holder balances?

Tags: etherscan, balances, mapping

How is the Etherscan TokenTracker able to show holder addresses?  The `balances` mapping of your average ERC20 token cannot be iterated over by index, nor can the length of the `mapping` be obtained.  So how might holder address information be available to Etherscan?

For example, you can view the Gnosis TokenTracker here and confirm a list of holders.

https://etherscan.io/token/Gnosis#balances

Next, if you view the contract source, you'll see that there's no code that explicitly returns the holder `address` by way of reference to `mapping (address => uint256) balances` or anything else.  (At least not that I can see.

https://etherscan.io/address/0x6810e776880c02933d47db1b9fc05908e5386b96#code

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your input.  They do indeed track `Transfer` events.  Additionally, if you use their token tracker to check a balance, and a balance returns, then they'll add that holder to the list.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think they've released the details of their implementation, but presumably they track `Transfer` events and update the known balances for each account as those events come in.

Comment: that's exactly what they do, and that's actually the only way to do it (cheaply). Another way would be scanning the entire Ethereum address base against the contract. And another would be to disassemble the contract and read the storage of the contract and extract its holders.

Comment: "that's exactly what they do" <-- could you provide a citation?

Comment: smarx , no I am speculating, with a high probability statement

Comment: Then I'm not sure why you commented.

Comment: to confirm your own speculation. I am also extracting tokens, and I use events.

Comment: You claimed to be confirming, but it turned out you were just agreeing. An upvote would be a better way to indicate that.

Comment: I already upvoted

Answer (score 1):

I just make a test on my own token and Mint event are not tracked whereas Transfer are.
It checks the balance of the sender/recipient after transactions.